# Add wrong device to software raid?

Tags: mdadm

a few days ago my raid5 had an crash. i replaced the hdd and add the wrong device to the raid (i add the device and not the partition)

Now the raid seems to work with follow config:

md0 : active raid5 sde1[4] sdd1[3] sdc[5] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      7814051840 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/4] [UU_UU]
      [>....................]  recovery =  1.0% (20819448/1953512960) finish=865.7min speed=37205K/sec

My question is what happend to sdc? why it's important first to create a FD partition and to add sdc1 instead of sdc?

What could happend with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

What happened is sdc got added to the array.  The reason you want to partition the drive instead of using the whole thing in the array is so that you can install grub to the drive so you can still boot from it if the/an another disk fails.